# issue with HelperOptions class in admin legacy controller Prestashop 8.0.2

Tags: prestashop-helper-classes

Helper Options class is still supported in prestashop 8.0.2 ? I implemented an legacy admin controller and styles not working and no data is saved in database when I send it form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WS3Z.png)

I expect find solution to this issue thanks